# How to provide Lambda S3 policy via AWS SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I'm trying to provide my Lambda function with the S3FullAccessPolicy policy. Note the target bucket is not configured within the `template.yaml` - it already exists. Considering the syntax examples from [this documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-sam-template-permissions/) I have three options:

1.AWS managed policy named:

```
  Policies:
  - S3FullAccessPolicy
```

2.AWS SAM policy template (SQSPollerPolicy) defined:

```
Policies:
  - S3FullAccessPolicy:
      BucketName: abc-bucket-name
```

3.Or an inline policy document:

```
  Policies:
  - Statement:
    ...
```

In trying #1 I get an error that says it seems to suggest I need to provide an arn. If this is the case where would I provide it? The error:

```
1 validation error detected: Value 'S3FullAccessPolicy' at 'policyArn' failed to satisfy constraint:
 Member must have length greater than or equal to 20
```

For #2 I provide the bucket name but it says that the policy is 'invalid'. I've tried adding quotes and replacing the name with an arn - but no luck.

And #3 - I can find the code for the policy [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-policy-template-list.html#s3-full-access-policy) but that's in yaml so I wonder if that's even what I'm supposed to be using.

What am I missing here? I'm open to using any one of these options but right now I'm 0/3.

The full Lambda function:

```
  testFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: lambda/testFunction/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Timeout: 900
      Policies:
        - S3FullAccessPolicy
```

Comment: For #2, what exactly was the error?, and what's the problem with using #3?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I used below template without any issues.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31


Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./hello_world/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Tracing: Active
      Policies:
        - S3FullAccessPolicy:
            BucketName: existingbucketname # bucket name without arn
```

Ran it using below command and it deployed successfully.

```
sam deploy --stack-name sample-stack --s3-bucket bucket-to-deploy --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

Comment: There are less permissive S3 policies than `S3FullAccessPolicy` that fit most lambda applications as well, such as `S3ReadPolicy` or `S3CrudPolicy`